# multiple condition in if statement in my sql trigger

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, database-connection

I am trying to give two condition in IF statement...these below two triggers are not showing any syntax error but they are not working also.

trigger :1 :

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `forumpostTrigger` ;

```
CREATE DEFINER = `livecomm`@`localhost` TRIGGER `forumpostTrigger` AFTER INSERT ON `forum_post`
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN if( (

SELECT count( * )
FROM forum_post
WHERE uid = new.uid
AND parent_id IS NOT NULL
AND is_answer_accepted ) >=30
)
THEN if( (

SELECT sum( vote_count )
FROM forum_post
WHERE uid = new.uid
AND parent_id IS NOT NULL
AND is_answer_accepted ) >=15
)
THEN
INSERT INTO user_badges( uid, bedge_id, is_active )
VALUES (
new.uid, '10', '1'
);

DELETE FROM user_badges WHERE uid = new.uid AND badge_id =9;

END IF ;

END IF ;

END
```

Trigger :2:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `forumpostTrigger` ;

CREATE DEFINER = `livecomm`@`localhost` TRIGGER `forumpostTrigger` AFTER INSERT ON `forum_post`
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN if( (
(

SELECT count( * )
FROM forum_post
WHERE uid = new.uid
AND parent_id IS NOT NULL
AND is_answer_accepted ) >=30
) && (
(

SELECT sum( vote_count )
FROM forum_post
WHERE uid = new.uid
AND parent_id IS NOT NULL
AND is_answer_accepted
) >=15
)
)
THEN
INSERT INTO user_badges( uid, bedge_id, is_active )
VALUES (
new.uid, '10', '1'
);

DELETE FROM user_badges WHERE uid = new.uid AND badge_id =9;

END IF ;

END
```

How to give multiple conditions for if statement like:
`if ((condition) && (condition))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `forumpostTrigger` ;

CREATE DEFINER = `livecomm`@`localhost` TRIGGER `forumpostTrigger` AFTER INSERT ON `forum_post`
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN if( (

SELECT count( * )
FROM forum_post
WHERE uid = new.uid
AND parent_id IS NOT NULL
AND is_answer_accepted ) =3
)
THEN
INSERT INTO user_badges( uid, badge_id, is_active )
VALUES (
new.uid, '9', '1'
);

END IF ;

if( (
SELECT count( * )
FROM forum_post
WHERE uid = new.uid
AND parent_id IS NOT NULL
AND is_answer_accepted ) =30
)
THEN if( (

SELECT sum( vote_count )
FROM forum_post
WHERE uid = new.uid
AND parent_id IS NOT NULL
AND is_answer_accepted ) >=15
)
THEN
INSERT INTO user_badges( uid, badge_id, is_active )
VALUES (
new.uid, '10', '1'
);

DELETE FROM user_badges WHERE uid = new.uid AND badge_id =9;

END IF ;

END IF ;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this syntax

```
IF condition1
IF condition2
BEGIN
..
END
```